# Insert URL data to a JSONArray

Tags: android, arrays, json

I have the following URL:

events_value = new URL("https://graph.facebook.com/me/events?access_token="+access_token);

URL gives me the following response:

https://graph.facebook.com/me/events?access_token=AAAAAAITEghMBAIBxLGB3PBYH3U5eF1reKAhNQQy85HWNuqGOl9NG2hsCCF8xLgMyc4bG51uo5dgt5c3M3UNcPnqhPVCtVZC4WVLveRmYRakas9AtQ

I tried to put that into a JSONArray:

```
JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(events_value);   //this where the problem comes     
final String[] array_spinner = new String[jArray.length()];
for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
    JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
    String jj=json_data.getString("name");
    array_spinner[i] = jj;         
}
```

I cannot enter events_value when creating the array.

Please help!

Comment: this https://graph.facebook.com/me/events?access_token=AAAAAAITEghMBAIBxLGB3PBYH3U5eF1reKAhNQQy85HWNuqGOl9NG2hsCCF8xLgMyc4bG51uo5dgt5c3M3UNcPnqhPVCtVZC4WVLveRmYRakas9AtQ link is expired . post json string with answer for quick help

Answer (score 1):

This code may help you. try this.

```
        JSONArray jArray = null;

        try {
        JSONObject json;
        // getting JSON string from URL
        if (url != null) {
            json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
            System.out.println("reading from url" + json);
        }

        // Getting Array of jArray
        jArray = json.getJSONArray(TAG_NAME);

        // looping through All jArray
        for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject c = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
            Log.d(TAG_TYPE, c.getString(TAG_NAME));//print in log cat

        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, what do you mean by "jParser" and "TAG_NAME"?

I think your solution will work, please help!

Comment: @TharakaNirmana  Its a JSON Parser object declare it as                               // Creating JSON Parser instance
  JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();  in your case TAG_NAME is "message" or "code" or "type" etc..

Answer (score 1):

```
public static JSONObject readJsonFromUrl(String url) throws IOException, JSONException {
    InputStream is = new URL(url).openStream();
    try {
      BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
      String jsonText = readAll(rd);
      JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonText);
      return json;
    } finally {
      is.close();
    }
  }

....
```

Then your code:

```
JSONArray jArray = (JSONArray) readJsonFromUrl(events_value);
final String[] array_spinner = new String[jArray.length()];
for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
    JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
    String jj=json_data.getString("name");
    array_spinner[i] = jj;         
}
```

Comment: when I types your first set of codes I get errors: readJsonFromUrl, jsonText, any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a typo in your question but events_value is a URL string not a JSONArray, so you will definitely get exception. Since the related url s token is expired i cannot see the exact response but, try with check if the response is a JSONObject or an JSONArray. a JSONArray has to '[' and ']' at the beginning and at the end, if not it is a JSONObject.

**Update**

Response string has data and paging fields. So data field is a JSONArray and paging JSONObject. For retrieving data use something like this:

```
JSONObject response = new JSONObject(responseString)
JSONArray data = response.getJSONArray("data");
```

Then for each item on the data array parse the attributes.

Comment: thank you for your comments, just renewed the access_token: please check: https://graph.facebook.com/me/events?access_token=AAAAAAITEghMBADQRAJ7yVSjZCZBHAgErhnTCNEfIbUudJpJjWWyeNjx3NocugVZBuGYsOGwT1hQpTQQ42U7WZBTDk62zJraCTaZClnNPMshDmgAd2VoIt